# Downloading empty java file Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

Currently I'm developing an application with help of Vaadin framework 8.0.

I need to download generated file from server. So I'm using FileDownloader and it's quite simple:

```
private void createButton() {
        Button downloadButton = new Button("download me)
        new FileDownloader(getStreamResource().extend(downloadButton))
}

private StreamResource getStreamResource() {
     StreamResource streamResource = new StreamResource(new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
         @Override
         public InputStream getStream() {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(generatedCode.getBytes);
        }
     }, "Generated.txt");
}
```

And all is ok when I'm using filename - "Generated.txt". But I need to save this file as a Java class. And when I'm using filename - "Generated.java" I'm just getting an empty file.

What I am doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any progress with this?
I've never used it but I think that you have to use **other Stream type** to create _.java_ file

Comment: Are you trying to write a `.class`file or a `.java` file? If it's a `class`, you are using the right class, otherwise, as @avix says, you should use a text `Stream` type.

Comment: @avix yup I have progress. Don't know exactly how it works but i've changed stream type to deprecated StringInputStream by org.codehaus.plexus.util and it worked.